# Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: Product

Tags: ant, migration-tool, winter19

Using the ANT migration tool I am able to port all my Standard and Custom objects except for **product**

My sample package.xml :

```
 <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>Contact</members>
    <members>Contract</members>
    <members>Opportunity</members>
    <members>Order</members>
    <members>Product</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

Command line log:

```
retrieveUnpackaged:
[sf:retrieve] Request for a retrieve submitted successfully.
[sf:retrieve] Request ID for the current retrieve task: 09S0k00*****
[sf:retrieve] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Succeeded
[sf:retrieve] Retrieve warnings (1):
[sf:retrieve] package.xml - Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: Product
[sf:retrieve] Finished request 09S0k00****** successfully.
```

Any reasons why and how I can retrieve Product?

Comment: `Product` is a *very* old object that was retired a long time ago but maintained for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API name for the Salesforce Product object is `Product2`. Put that in your `package.xml` and you should be able to retrieve the metadata.

Note that the same is true of Pricebook (`Pricebook2`), but not of Pricebook Entry (`PricebookEntry`).